# Automatically correct values by default value function

Tags: qgis, layers, fields-attributes

When I add data to a layer, it sometimes occurs that there is a '__' at the end of a number.
I know that there is the option to correct these values manually if I use the command "replace( "flurstueck",'_','')" within the fieldcalculator. I would now like to use this command as the default value in the layer option.  But it seems to be not working here. It says "apply default value on update", which update does it mean?
[image]

Comment: Whenever you edit the feature, the default value will be used. That said, please do yourself the favour and do **not** delete these underscores. They are part of the official parcel designation in Germany and function as unique ID, allowing you to link e.g. owner data, etc. They also separate numerator and denominator (Zähler & Nenner) for split parcels. So removing them removes vital information on the parcel ID.

Comment: I know that this number is unique and I will certainly not change the number itself I just want to delete the "__" at the end of some numbers, which are beeing generated by a tool that is converting all our data.

Comment: @Erik "Whenever you edit the feature, the default value will be used" even this is only working when editing exactly this object. But I want it to do this replacement for all objects.

Comment: Then run it once for all objects via the field calculator? Or ask Claas Leiner if he could add a field containing this exact value for you.

Comment: Ok, thanks but that was no help at all. I did run it already for all objects as I mentioned before, but sometimes I add some objects and in that case, I dont want to run that command manually again and again. Also I wrote him already but he seems to be pretty busy. Is he the only one with such a converter or how do you knew?

Comment: So, you copy&paste parcels into your existing file? If the file is only part of one QGIS Project you could add a `virtual field` which updates regularly.

Comment: I don't understand: the expression you have works for me: if I introduce a new value containing underscore `_`, it will be deleted automatically. So this is what you want, I don't see the problem?

Comment: If i add objects with the function "Merge Layers", it doesn't apply the default value, so I have to manually use the fieldcalculator edit these objects.
So I want this to be automatically applied to all objects, for example when I open the project.